# Jenkins curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: tomcat, docker, curl, jenkins

I'm doing a declarative pipeline with several stages. And in one of the stages i want to deploy a war file on a running docker with the tomcat image. For this i use the command curl. But i always get the following error on jenkins:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0 15.7M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    ....

            stage ('System test') {
            steps{
                bat 'docker run -d -p 9205:8080 tomcat:7.0.82'
                dir('some/dir/something'){
                    script{                             
                        bat 'curl -T "C:/path/to/solution.war" "http://tomcat:tomcat@localhost:9205/manager/text/deploy?path=/solution.war&update=true"'                                
                    }
                    input 'Do you want to proceed?'
                }
            }
        }
```

Things i already tried:

- curl -L
- netstat -a -p TCP -n | grep 3000 (port used) .. To see if there are no more multiple connections
- Curl with Credentials

Answer (score 0):

looks like tomcat is only listening on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) inside container whereas it should be listening on 0.0.0.0.

Have you tried to curl inside the container using the following command

```
docker exec -it <container_name> curl 'curl -T "C:/path/to/solution.war" "http://tomcat:tomcat@localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/solution.war&update=true"'
```

if this works then you have to configure Tomcat to listen on all IP

1. Edit `tomcat/conf/server.xml`.
2. Specify a bind address for that connector:

   ```
   <Connector 
       port="8080" 
       protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       address="0.0.0.0"
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       redirectPort="8443" 
     />
   ```

Hope this helps.